# Return multiple statements in Python Flask in the same route

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to put two variables from the Zillow API into my Flask App. The issue that I am running into is that my statements are returning all the values instead of their appropriate variable. See screenshot below:

[image]

The screenshot shows 3 numbers for each line statement. The correct output should be "The price of the house is 1011065" and "The price of rent is 2150". The third number is the size of the home, I just didn't write out the statement for it yet.

*by the way, I know the reason this is happening is because I am pulling all the 3 variables in one return statement, but in my html file, I am only calling one of the variables in the return statement per line*

I have two python files. One is pulling all the data from the zillow api (we will call this zillow.py) and the other (flask.py) and the oher is the flask app.

The zillow.py is returning the price of the house and the price of the rent via this function:

```
def zillow_data(address,zipcode):
   # generic code that pulls data from zillow
   house_price = zillow_api.house_price
   rent_price = zillow_api.rent_price
   home_size = zillow_api.home_size

   return house_price, rent_price, home_size
```

Now I am trying to show the data in the front-end of my flask app:

```
@app.route('/output',  methods=['POST'])
def success():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        address = request.form['address']
        zipcode = request.form['zipcode']
        house_price = zillow.zillow_data(address, zipcode)
        rent_price = zillow.zillow_data(address, zipcode)
        home_size = zillow.zillow_data(address, zipcode)
        
        
        return render_template('success.html',
                               house_price = house_price,
                               rent_price = rent_price,
                               home_size = home_size).format()
    else:
        pass
```

Here is the success.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Success</title>
</head>
<body>
<center><h2>The price of the house is {{ zestimate }} <br>
  The price of rent is fvfv{{ rent_zestimate }} <br>
  Square footage of the home is {{ home_size }}</h2></center>
</body>
</html>
```

I know this is the greatest solution (I am new to Python and Flask), so any suggestions on how to better accomplish my task would be appreciated. My end-goal is to add more variables to the output. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
price_map = {}

price_map['house_price'] = house_price
price_map['rent_price'] = rent_price
price_map['home_size'] = home_size

return render_template('success.html',price_map).format()
```

Instead of adding more variables, you could create an dict and pass it to template and fetch the values in renderer.

Answer (score 2):

`return house_price, rent_price, home_size` returns a *tuple* structured as `(house_price, rent_price, home_price,)`

So you have to replace

```
house_price = zillow.zillow_data(address, zipcode)
rent_price = zillow.zillow_data(address, zipcode)
home_size = zillow.zillow_data(address, zipcode)
```

with:

```
house_price, rent_price, home_price = zillow.zillow_data(address, zipcode)
```

Because every call to `zillow.zillow_data(address, zipcode)` just returns same tuple over and over.